# F# Square Root on Int

Tags: types, f#, floating-point, int, sqrt

I'm building a program in F# in which i need to do the Square Root of a Integer value.
I've searched and found none function which allows to doing that without the use of a cast `int -> float`.

Is there a function that allows to make the square root of an integer without an unnecessary cast?

Comment: Stepping back a bit: How would you define the square root of an integer in the first place? What is the square root of 8? Should it be 2 (floor of 2.828) or 3 (ceil of 2.828) or 3 (`Math.round` of 2.828)? It is not well defined, and depending on your application, you may need to pick one of those options.

Comment: Anton's question is a good one. I have another question: **Why** do you need this? (Or why do you think you need this?) Because I've found that when someone asks for X without explaining why they need it, and X is difficult/impossible (e.g., a square root function on integers), it usually turns out that they are *really* trying to do Y, and they think that X is the only way to do Y. So then we can say "Well, there's another way to get to Y without doing X, and it looks like this," and that's often a better solution than the difficult/impossible X.

Comment: I want literally that for some test, find the square root of a int type.

Comment: "For some test" as in "for some homework assignment"?

Comment: For curiosity, not everyone who ask stupid question is stupid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want a function that takes an integer and returns its square root as a floating point, then using a `float` function to convert the int to a floating point and then calling `sqrt` is the way to go:

```
sqrt (float n)
```

In principle, F# could allow this conversion implicitly, but I think it does not do it because it because it is not clear what square root of an integer should be (as discussed in the comments). In C#, you can write `Math.Sqrt(n)`, but this works because C# allows implicit conversion from `int` to `float` anywhere in your program.

If you want a square root if integers that returns integers, then there is no standard way of doing that (as discussed in the comments), so it's up to you to implement the functionality you need.

Answer (score 0):

I have a hard time understanding why the limitation to `int` input but if that is important one could employ a divide & conquer algorithm. This is a lot slower than `sqrt (float n)` on any CPU architecture with hardware floats.

```
let isqrt n =
  let rec loop b e =
    let i = (b + e) >>> 1
    let i2 = i*i
    if i2 = n then
      i
    else
      let nb, ne =
        if i2 > n then
          b, i
        else
          i, e
      if nb = b && ne = e then
        // Check i - 1 and i + 1 to see if either is a better fit than i
        let imin  = i - 1
        let imax  = i + 1
        let i2min = imin*imin
        let i2max = imax*imax
        let d     = n - i2    |> abs
        let dmin  = n - i2min |> abs
        let dmax  = n - i2max |> abs
        if d < dmin && d < dmax then
          i
        elif dmin < dmax then
          imin
        else
          imax

      else
        loop nb ne
  loop 1 n

open FsCheck

let isqrtProperty n =
  n > 1 ==> fun () ->
    let r     = isqrt n
    let rmin  = r - 1
    let rmax  = r + 1

    let r2    = r*r
    let rmin2 = rmin*rmin
    let rmax2 = rmax*rmax

    let d     = n - r2     |> abs
    let dmin  = n - rmin2  |> abs
    let dmax  = n - rmax2  |> abs

    r >= 0 && d <= dmin && d <= dmax

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
  let config = { Config.Quick with MaxTest = 10000; MaxFail = 100000 }
  Check.One ("isqrt property", config, isqrtProperty)
  0
```